# How to close git commit editor?

Tags: git, command-line, version-control

I just executed a command `$ git commit` and it opens a new editor. But I'm trying to close that new commit editor. How to do this? I'm using Git for Windows.

Comment: not a complete answer, but one way to avoid the editor is to use the "-m" option. E.g. after $ git add <your_changes>, then do $ git commit -m "my changes; I'm avoiding the editor!"

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl How do you enter new lines in `-m` ?

Comment: @KorayTugay: it's a good question but i don't know. generally, i would discourage long commit messages (e.g. with new lines) and encourage one sentence messages. brief and crisp commit messages tend to be more insightful here

Comment: @Koray Tugay after first double quotation marks, you press Enter and commit command does not end

Comment: Actually, that depends on your shell. On Unix-like systems, most shells behave like you describe, but on Windows, you probably need to sacrifice to Azathoth and/or install some third-party tools from a sunken continent.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

Save the file in the editor. If it's Emacs: <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save then <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to quit or if it's vi: <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

Press `esc` first to get out from editing. (in windows/vi)

Comment: The user needs to close the editor in addition to saving the file, so for Emacs it's actually `Ctrl-X Ctrl-C`.

Comment: Updated... I knew that, but like most emacs commands, they're so ingrained in me that I forget what they are... I just do them.

Comment: If you use emacsclient, you can close it with `C-x #`

Comment: On my window, I am surprised `Ctrlx-x` command is enough to abort commit.

Comment: what is emacs? The OP asks for windows... just ESC does not help, the answer is incomprehensible, don't know why it was marked as answer

Comment: On Mac, the default editor is Vim, so press ESC first, then type :wq + ENTER

Answer (score 326):

Had troubles as well. On Linux I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (and <kbd>Y</kbd> to confirm) and then I was back on the shell ready to pull/push.

On **Windows GIT Bash** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> would do nothing and found out it works quite like vi/vim. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter inline insert mode. Type the description at the very top, press <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit insert mode, then type `:x!` (now the cursor is at the bottom) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to save and exit.

If typing `:q!` instead, will exit the editor without saving (and commit will be aborted)

Comment: this is the answer for me for windows

Comment: esc :x! - This isn't just undiscoverable its as if someone was playing hide and seek with functionality.

Comment: Work perfectly on windows Git Bash, this is the answer for me.

Comment: Nothing here is specific to Linux or WIndows or Mac. It sounds like you had configured `nano` (?) as your editor on Linux, and had not configured an editor on Windows, which caused `git` to choose its default, which is `vi`

Answer (score 113):

After writing commit message, just press **Esc** Button and then write **:wq** or **:wq!** and then **Enter** to close the unix file.

Comment: this solution is the one that work  on Git Gui bash for window

Comment: ! This reminded me of the University days, when we did some Unix vi editing things, after a long wrote some **`:wq`** commands

Comment: `:x` is a shortcut for `:wq` in Vim.

Answer (score 29):

Better yet, configure the editor to something you are comfortable with (gedit as an example):

```
git config --global core.editor "gedit"
```

You can read the current configuration like this:

```
git config core.editor
```

You can also add the commit message from the command line.

```
git commit -m "blablabla"
```

and the editor will not be opened in the first place.

Answer (score 27):

After `git commit` command, you entered to the editor, so first hit `i` then start typing. After committing your message hit `Ctrl + c` then `:wq`

Comment: You should edit your commit message. Then follow above. Solution works for windows.

Comment: Nothing here is specific to Windows. This is how  you save and exit if your editor is `vi` or a derivative.

Answer (score 20):

In Mac,
Press `shift+Z shift+Z` (capital Z twice).

Comment: This is not Mac-specific, but editor-specific. In `vi`, this will abort without saving the file.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatives to Nano (might make your life easier):

On Windows, use notepad. In command prompt type:

`git config core.editor notepad`

On Ubuntu / Linux, use text editor (gedit). In terminal window type:

`git config core.editor gedit`

Comment: Gedit is a rather lackluster editor; you should probably find one you like, and install that instead, and configure it as your default editor.

Answer (score 4):

You Just clicking the key.

first press ESC + enter and
then press :x + enter

Comment: Another redundant `vi` answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem I received a ">" like prompt and I couldn't commit.
I replace the " in the comment with ' and it works.

I hope this help someone!

Comment: Aha! I had gotten stuck with this ">" prompt too. From reading your comment I figured out that since I had used an apostrophe in a contraction in my comment, the terminal was waiting for me to close out the quote! Finally I'm free!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the key combination that gets you there to the > prompt but it is not a bash prompt that I know. I usually get it by accident. Ctrl+C (or D) gets me back to the $ prompt.

Comment: It's  the shell's secondary prompt, which is displayed if you are in a multi-line string (i.e. you typed an opening single or double quote, and have not yet typed the corresponding closing quote).

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're using Sublime as your commit editor, you [need the `-n -w` flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42321341/792238), otherwise git keeps thinking your commit message is empty and aborting.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue just in case this helps you.

When you hit the command `git commit --amend`. It opens a default editor. Now, the question was how to close this. I have just resolved this so here it is if it helps:

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Press <kbd>Y</kbd> to select Yes

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (This command saves the commit message you are editing and brings you out of editor)

Try `git log` command to verify your changes

Comment: This seems to be advice for users of the `nano` editor.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my terminal on Mac opens Joe editor when `git commit`. I had to press `Ctrl + K H` to get to the help, this informed me to press `Ctrl + K + X` to exit.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly works depends on which editor you are in. Many of the answers here explain how to exit `vi` or `vim` (<kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by `:wq` at the prompt to save the file and exit), with some other editors thrown in; but none of them really discuss how you would know.

Git out of the box examines your `VISUAL` environment variable. If this is unset, it will default to `vi` on Unix-like platforms.

```
export VISUAL=nano
```

to select `nano` instead. (It's not an editor I particularly like or recommend, even though it was designed specifically to be easy for beginners to understand and learn.) Obviously, if you prefer `emacsclient` or `sublime` or `code`, put that after the equals sign instead. No spaces on either side of the equals sign! Put this in your shell's startup file (`.bash_profile` or `.zprofile` or `.profile` or etc, depending on which shell you are using) to make this setting the default in new terminal instances.

Another common scenario is if you started typing in a multi-line string at the shell prompt.

```
bash$ git commit -m "here is my commit message
> oops, I forgot the final quote
> how do I fix this?
> haaaaaaalp
```

At this point, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to give up and start over. The `>` prompt is the shell's secondary prompt (it can be configured by changing the value of `PS2`, but most people don't) which is displayed when you are in the middle of a quoted string. If you want to commit with the message you already typed, simply add the missing final single or double quote:

```
bash$ git commit -m 'small changes
> '
[main 0badd09]
 736 files changed, 136756 insertions(+)
bash$ _
```

Just to reiterate, Git and your editor are two different components (and so is your OS, your shell, your terminal, your programming language(s), etc). When you first get started, it's probably confusing and distracting to figure out which part controls which behavior. Down the line, this is how you end up with an extremely flexible and customizable and thus extremely efficient personal environment.

(On Windows, Git commonly comes bundled with Bash because at the time they started to figure things out, there was no sane native shell for Windows. These days, things are slightly different, to the extent that "sane" and Windows can be used in the same sentence without negations or complex qualifiers, but it probably doesn't make sense to go back and start over with a different baseline.)