# Git screen after push can't go back

Tags: git, command

After I run Git push origin i got these screen. But is not clear for me how to get out of it. Pls help.
[Git screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd8UH.jpg)

Comment: Please copy the text into the question. Do not link to screenshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - How to close commit editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239368/git-how-to-close-commit-editor)

Answer (score 1):

This is commit message screen. You write your message or leave it as it is and leave editor (nano).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> is a shortcut to exit nano