# How to clone and merge a specific pull request made by other in to my own repository locally

Tags: git, github

What will be the way of clone the pull request into my repo locally? https://github.com/RoboSherlock/robosherlock/pull/215
This is the pull request I want to merge into my fork or locally. I search some questions here but that looks different, I want to merge these pull requests into my repo. This pull request is in the master branch but I have to merge in the noetic branch.

Comment: I need some clarification. We are looking at the upstream repo. You are saying you want to merge the pull request branch into your own fork of that repo?

Comment: Not branch, only this pull request into my branch which is noetic but this pull request was made on the master branch. I have also a forked repo of this Robosherlock repo. Now I have to only merge this pull request only to my fork( which I will also do first locally and then make a pull request to my repo).

Comment: So you are saying you want to make a whole new pull request? Then start a branch, cherry pick `bb7efd3` onto it, and push the branch.

Comment: Git fundamentally does not merge branches into branches. It merges commits into commits. Branches don't matter in Git, in other words. The commits are all that matter. (The branch names aren't useless though: they help you, and Git, *find* the commits. But that's basically it: they're just commit-finders. It's the *commits* that matter.)

Comment: Yeah, I have to look in to commits, this pull request have 2 commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key fact: The last commit in the pull request branch is `bb7efd3`.

So the direct way to do this is that you would get onto the `noetic` branch and merge `bb7efd3` into it. You will have one small merge conflict to resolve and then you're all set.

---

I think if I wanted to do this through a pull request I would get onto `noetic`, rebase the two commits of the original pull request branch onto it, call that a new branch, push my new branch, and create the pull request. Here, I'll show you:

```
git switch noetic
git rebase --onto noetic bb7efd3~2 bb7efd3
# ... resolve merge conflict and finish rebase ...
# ... you are now on a detached head ...
git switch -c newbranch
```

As you can see, the result is exactly the topology you want — a new branch off of `noetic` that looks like the old pull request branch:

```
% git log --oneline -n 3 mybranch
5242afa (HEAD -> mybranch) Fix wrong constructor name
3ef17e6 RegionFilter with markers
84cc713 (origin/noetic, noetic) changed default demo pipeline. no tf lookups anymore to avoid tf lookup errors in the tutorials
```

So now you can push `newbranch` and form a pull request in the ordinary way.

Comment: Regarding your first way, if I merge bb7efd3 into my noetic branch will the above d063211 commit will automatically merge or do I also have to do it separately?

Comment: The question makes no sense. When you say, in the ordinary way, `git merge mybranch`, you are merging _one commit_. It doesn't matter how many other commits you think are "on" the branch `mybranch`; that idea is fundamentally wrong. The history preceding the `mybranch` commit (and the history preceding current branch) is not unimportant, but only that one commit is being merged. To ask whether some other commit will merge is meaningless.

Comment: So when you say "this pull request have 2 commits" you have basically misunderstood what Git is, what a commit is, and what a branch is. And what a merge is! The pull request is about _one_ commit, the last commit on that branch. Hence the form of my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I am new to this git and still learning stuff.

Comment: let me try these. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, remember, nothing is written on tablets of jade, as long as you have pushed all your existing work. If you try something and you don't like it, you can always throw it away and clone again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240638/discussion-between-ab-danyia-and-matt).

Comment: If you don't understand what Git is, please read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/.

Comment: Thank you @matt for this brief introductory blog on git. I read it and get some core concepts. Now I did resolve the merge conflict after `git rebase --onto noetic bb7efd3~2 bb7efd3`  now after doing `git rebase --continue` my terminal got stuck to it. Do you know the reson?

Comment: I don't know what "my terminal got stuck to it" means. Perhaps it is waiting for your editor to submit the commit message?

Comment: hi @matt, i attach a screenshot in your answer of problem

Comment: Well don't do that. You want to edit something, edit _your_ question. You leave my answer alone. Thank you.

Comment: OK to it's exactly as I said. That is your editor (vim) and it is waiting for you to save the commit message and exit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239368/git-how-to-close-commit-editor

Comment: Thank you @matt for your time. Now it is working